# Get Drupal user into WordPress

Tags: cms

I have a Drupal site, and into it, a WordPress site.

I would like to know how to get user info of drupal site in WordPress site ?

in fact if your a user of wwww.mydrupalsite.com, how can I pass user info to www.mydrupalinfo.com/wordpress. ?

Thank for answer !

Comment: Definitely a pain. Read the following: [http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#Drupal](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#Drupal)
[http://blog.room34.com/archives/4530](http://blog.room34.com/archives/4530)

Answer (score 1):

In short, to bring over your users from Drupal to Wordpress you need to fill the wordpress table users (wp_users if you´re using the standard wordpress prefix) with the information of the "users" table of your drupal site. Just make sure you don't delete the admin users of your wordpress site or you won't be able to login afterwards.